# firestore security rules / check field type in nested object

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

How do I use belows generic function for nested fields? I have this document below which lives at `/userdata/{uid}`:

[image]

As can be seen `userBirthTime` is a map, it contains another map called `birthTime` which in turn has the fields I want to veryify for their types e.g. check that the incoming `year` is of type `int` before it's allowed to be stored in firestore.

How would I do this? Is it even possible for nested fields? I tried with

```js
function isInteger(fieldName) { return request.resource.data[fieldName] is int }
```

and then used it like this

```js
isInteger('userBirthTime.birthTime.year')
```

with the overall security rule being this

```js
match /userdata/{uid} {
  allow write: if isInteger('userBirthTime.birthTime.year')
}
```

but that's just always returning `true` even if I try with a `string` as `fieldName` rather than the required `int` type?!

What am I doing wrong? Is it the fact that's a nested field and not a top-level one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the dot notation doesn't work in security rules (although it returns false always):

[image]

```
// the request body
"data": {
  "userBirthTime": {
    "birthTime": {
      "year": "string"
    }
  }
}
```

Changing the rules to this works for me:

```
function isInteger(fieldName) { 
  return request.resource.data.userBirthTime.birthTime[fieldName] is int 
}

match /userdata/{uid} {
  allow write:  if isInteger('year'); // other fields
}
```

Comment: I see... hm... ok, the major downside of this of course is then I can't have a single generic function anymore that works for other fields in other maps as well but I literally have to hardcode the 'path' down to every nested field 
For example, I can't use `isInteger()` to check the number of dogs as well and so on: `isInteger('userPets.numberDogs')`

Comment: @Tom yeah but on the other side maybe you can write a function to check all children of birthTime and so on for pets maybe.

Comment: I updated the screenshot above to show more maps inside the root of this document. To clarify the subject at hand: my goal is to have one generic function that checks for types such as `int` or `string` that works for various fields inside this document that live on various depths and locations inside this document. For example: `isInteger('userBirthTime.birthTime.year')` but also `isInteger('userBirthTime.eventDetail.startValue')`. That's the tricky thing, how do I do that with a single generic function? 

Comment: @Tom I mean you would have to pass the value yourself then like: `isInteger(request.resource.data.userBirthtime.birthTime.year)` now the isInteger can be used anywhere or something similar. You can pass multiple arguments in function to pass the request object and do some processing.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution for better **generalization** of objects is one which uses the [`.get()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.Map#get) method.

```js
match /userdata/{uid} {
  allow write: if isInteger(['userBirthTime', 'birthTime', 'year']);
}

function isInteger(keys) {
  let value = request.resource.data.get(keys, null);
  return value != null && value is int;
}
```

In case `.get()` is unable to find a value at the provided key path array, the function will return a default value of `null`.